# Exclude already linked stylesheet for a particular page or how to set priorities to stylesheet

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation framework for first time in my project. I have included [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) in a partial page and loading it into main page. My problem is foundation framework styles overwrites on fullcalendar styles.

I have included fullcalendar stylesheet and jQuery files in partial page so that fullcalendar styles get high priority but doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem? (Can I just exclude foundation framework styles in a partial page, if yes then how?)

Comment: Link your source or try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure that you are including the JavaScript link to fullcalendar at the end of the document, so foundation and other libraries can start first.

```
<script src="foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

Secondly if you would like to exclude the script depending on the page you are on, you'll have to use some conditional formatting. 
With PHP:

```
if(!basename(__FILE__) == 'pagetoexclude.php') {
  echo '<script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Calendar plugin is in partial page loading into main page. So if I remove/disable fullcalendar.js file, it effects other controller in main page too. So this solution doesn't work.